# How to pull and display data from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Background**

I'm building a basic task management app (to better understand Rails) in which you input the name / description of a task and indicate its priority (by saying whether it's important and/or urgent). Based on the importance and urgency, I place it into a particular quadrant / list.

When the user goes to `/tasks/index` I want to:

- Pull all of their tasks from the DB
- Loop through each task and display them in the correct quadrant / list

Here's part of the `/controllers/tasks_controller.rb`:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tasks = Task.where(user_id: @user_id)
  end
end
```

The tables I want to append each task to in `/views/tasks/index.html.erb` use the following structure and naming convention:

```
<table>
  <tbody id="quadrant-X"> <!-- where 'X' is an integer, 1-4 -->
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      <% render @tasks %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here's the @tasks partial (i.e. `/views/tasks/_task.html.erb`):

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <%=task.description%>
  </td>
</tr>
```

**Issues**

1. Tasks don't render in the tables (no errors are thrown)
2. I need a reusable way to render each task in the appropriate table

Comment: The rails way is to put the iterator into the view and render each task in a partial.

Comment: Not sure why this is getting down voted. Can someone (@DavidHoelzer ?) point me to some documentation or a tutorial? I'm particularly interested in how to do this in a reusable way considering each task could appear in one of four tables.

Comment: I've already outlined how to do it.  You'll find it in any rails tutorial if you look into partials.  You are likely being downvoted because people feel that you could have simply googled the answer, but I can't be sure since I wasn't one of the down voters. :)

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. (Note: this is why people are downvoting).

Comment: I've already read through through the Rails documentation on partials [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) and parts of [this chapter](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/user_microposts) from Hart'ls 'Ruby on Rails' book, have implemented what I've read, and it's not rendering. Guess I'll just keep searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could include the whole table in the partial and render it inside your view (`app/views/tasks/index.html.erb`) for each one of your tables.

Example for `app/views/tasks/_task.html.erb`:

```
<table>
  <tbody id="quadrant-<%= priority %>">
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      <% if task.priority == priority %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= task.description %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Example for `app/views/tasks/index.html.erb`:

```
<h2>Priority 1</h2>
<%= render 'task', priority: 1 %>

<h2>Priority 2</h2>
<%= render 'task', priority: 2 %>

<h2>Priority 3</h2>
<%= render 'task', priority: 3 %>

<h2>Priority 4</h2>
<%= render 'task', priority: 4 %>
```

This will give you the flexibility to put each list wherever you want on your view, but this comes with a cost since you will iterate your task list 4 times (1 for each priority).

Although you could fix the this problem if you move the iteration out of the partial and include it in the view, inside a script that inserts each row on the correct table (quadrant).

Modified `app/views/tasks/index.html.erb` using JQuery:

```
<h2>Priority 1</h2>
<%= render 'task', priority: 1 %>

<h2>Priority 2</h2>
<%= render 'task', priority: 2 %>

<h2>Priority 3</h2>
<%= render 'task', priority: 3 %>

<h2>Priority 4</h2>
<%= render 'task', priority: 4 %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
    $('#quadrant-<%= task.priority %>').append('<tr><td><%= task.description %></td></tr>');
  <% end %>
</script>
```

Just replace hard-coded priority numbers (1..4) with your variables and this should, at least, point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I got the first approach somewhat working. Couple questions: (1) For the first approach all of the tasks are displaying in each of the quadrants. In looking at the code, how is `priority` changes based on the task's priority? Am I supposed to create 4 different partials, one for each table? (2) What exactly would go in the partial if I took the JQuery approach?

Comment: (1) I updated the answer to add the missing conditional needed to filter the correct tasks, based on their priority. Again, change priority for your own variable/validation. Since you are passing variables to the partial, you just need one partial.

Comment: (2) Just remove the loop (that is, everything inside <tbody> tag).

Comment: How is your model defined? Which attributes are needed to determine priority (1-4)?

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.